# Mysql - Bulk Insert 0.5 Million+ rows

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

I need to insert over Half a Million rows in Mysql database table. I have searched through internet but suggested option doesn't as per my requirement. Following are my constraints :

1. We are using .Net C#
2. We cannot have file option available which we can load into the table directly.
3. A slight lag in time would acceptable.

Please could you all suggest what option I can use to insert bulk rows in table.

Comment: Can you expand on constraint 2 please.

Comment: I cannot use to fill up the file with huge data and load that file into database table.

Comment: *"A slight lag in time would acceptable."* define "slight" lag is that like 10 ms?

Comment: lets say for 100000 rows we can tolerate 2-5 seconds

Comment: the best next option MySQL provides is using multinsert syntax like `INSERT INTO .... VALUES(..), (..)` but you can hit the packet size limit and you will lose time building the insert..

Comment: *" I have searched through internet but suggested option doesn't as per my requirement. "* Also you should post what you have tryed..

Comment: MySQL 8.0.17 has a bulk loader utility built into the new shell